# Cambiar tipo de fuente en iTextSharph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itextsharp

Estoy creando un documento PDF, sin embargo, me gustaría colocar otro tipo de fuente, diferente a las que tiene iTextSharph, lo he intentado de esta manera y no ha funcionado:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Fonts-pdf_funciones_internas\\lucida-sans\\LSANS.ttf", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la forma más sencilla es embebiendo tu fuente como un recurso en tu aplicación.
Nosotros lo tenemos como un recurso llamado "UniSansItalic" y lo utilizamos de esta forma:

```
var fontUniSansItalic = BaseFont.CreateFont("Uni Sans Italic.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, Properties.Resources.UniSansItalic, null);
```

La otra forma es buscando la fuente entre las instaladas en la máquina, de esta forma, pero tenés que estar seguro que está instalada.

```
var fontTitle = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 27.5f);
```

¡Suerte!